# Theme automatically inserting "more" tag on every post

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

I'm using the free Lensa theme and it seems like it inserts a "more" tag in every single post when viewing by category, and the point at which it inserts it is proportional to the length of the post.

http://daswanderlust.com/blog

That quote is only about 10 words long but gets truncated after the 6th word or so. I admit I don't have much experience with php, but I'm assuming this should be a pretty easy fix since the code seems to do this universally across any type of post. Any ideas/tips on which files to go through first? What sort of function I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you have a link to the source code for the theme?

Comment: Check your `archive.php` file and see whether the theme uses `the_excerpt()` (which will insert a more tag) or `the_content()`.

Comment: Also, what behavior do you want instead?

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes, the source code is located at http://colorlabsproject.com/themes/lensa/ I just want all of the posts to displayed without the "more" tag unless I explicitly insert one into the post

Comment: @EricHolmes I found this snippet of code in the archive.php so I'm guessing its using a custom excerpt function. I tried replacing colabs_custom_excerpt() with the_content() but it didn't do anything.Not sure if it matters but the theme comes with an editor that lets me modify files in the Dashboard, and that's how I'm changing it

`<div class="entry-content">
   <?php colabs_custom_excerpt(); ?>
   <p class="more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e("More","colabsthemes"); ?></a></p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->`

Comment: I found the theme's home page. There is no code there and the download like, even if were willing to go through that hassle, takes me to a signup page.

Comment: Find the code for `colabs_custom_excerpt`. Look for `function colabs_custom_excerpt` and [edit] the code into the question but you better check the theme's TOS. They don't make the source readily available so there may be conditions to prevent you from doing so. Please don't paste long code blocks into comments. That is nearly unreadable.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't think I can post the function on here after a quick skim through of their TOS. Anyway, if I were to find every instance where the custom excerpt function is called and change that to `the_excerpt`, should that work?

Comment: Yes, I think that replacing their custom excerpt with the default `the_excerpt` should do it, but I can't be sure. I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your archive.php file, you would want to replace this:

`<div class="entry-content">
    <?php colabs_custom_excerpt(); ?>
    <p class="more">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php _e("More","colabsthemes"); ?>
        </a>
        </p>`

With this

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); // or the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

The theme creator is MANUALLY inserting the more button (as you can see). You could just remove the paragraph containing the More button, or replace their custom function with the native functionality (both given).

If you plan on updating your theme ever (which I recommend you do), I strongly recommend creating a child theme, which is explained thoroughly [here](http://designisphilosophy.com/24-days-of-wordpress/creating-a-wordpress-child-theme-the-smart-way/), and do any file/style changes there, instead of the theme itself. Just copy over the files into the child theme and edit there. This way, you won't lose any changes when you update your theme!

Answer (score 0):

The theme uses a custom excerpt function named `colabs_custom_excerpt`. The OP believes that the theme's TOS prevents posting the code here so one of the few option is the replace occurances of `colab_custom_excerpt` in the theme with the WordPress default excerpt function `the_excerpt`. Of course, you could also replace it with a custom excerpt function of your own devising. You may need to use `the_content` rather than `the_excerpt`. Try that if `the_excerpt` does not give you result you want.

Without access to the code, it is impossible to say what the consequences will be but given the function involved I doubt there will be serious problems.

If this theme is written in such a way as to be "child-able", I'd suggest creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) rather than editing the third party theme directly.